# body size of 100vh not working in responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive

I set my body height to 100vh ( I even tried 100 %) in normal layout in desktop it works fine. But when the vertical height of the browser is reduced the body including the sidebar and main content present inside them are not with 100% height are not occupying the full height of the window. How do I proceed thanks in advance.

I tried also setting

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  height:100%;
}
```

**Note:**
I am using bootstrap v3.3.7 scss for other internal layouting.

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7d7nLrfj/1/)

**Note2:**  This is what happens to sidebar when height is shrinked not the width. same happens for body too.it is not occupying full height of screen

[image]

Comment: Can we see some code, please?

Comment: You may want to add a working https://jsfiddle.net example for us

Comment: While I try it on JsFiddle, I found it is working well, your `html` and `body` are taking 100% of the window but only the element is not long enough to fill all of it, may I know what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to keep the body with its main content and side bar with height always occupying full width of the window with navbar at top even when window height is shrinked

Comment: It is a different between 'the navbar overlay the side bar + content' and 'the navbar place before the side bar + content' and it both mean 'at top'

Comment: could you explain more. I didnt get that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the CSS after the `/* New Arrival */`

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh; /* use min-height 100 vh instead of height to allow extended height with large content */
}
ul { margin: 0} /* Remove the white space because of the ul margin */
nav { background-color: #ff9090; }
/* Uncomment the following line to see different effect */
/* nav { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; } */
.sidebar { background-color: #ff6d00; }
.maincontainer { background-color: #aaa; }

/* min-height and height CSS properties of .appcontent should be applied as following to take the fill height effect. display: table; to allow it's children to take the effect as well */
.appcontent { min-height: 100vh; height: 100%; display: table; }
/* Since .appcontent display as table, it's children should be displayed as table row */
.appcontent > * { display: table-row; }

/* To avoid the first 'table row' take most height of parent, set it's height to 0. The broser should be able to render the correct height */
.appcontent .sidebar, .appcontent .sidebar > * { height: 0; }
/* Like the table case, the immediate elements inside a table-row element should display as table cell */
.appcontent .sidebar,
.appcontent .maincontainer > * { display: table-cell; }
```

Check the demo on https://jsfiddle.net/7d7nLrfj/3/

Answer (score 1):

for me, the problem was the missing `overflow: auto`

```css
html, body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```